# How to remove Dot Net Nuke Version from title

Tags: title, dotnetnuke

For some reason all my DNN pages (I have installed DNN automatically using Godaddy) have the DNN version (Alpha Version 5.2.000) at the end of every page title automatically

how can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if you are using the aplha version it will remain there. solution is ... install a stable version (or upgrade).